# Is this an incorrect warning?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, initialization, warnings

Let's see this code pattern I'm seeing often:

```
struct Foo
{
    template <typename T>
    T* as1() { /* ... */ }

    template <typename T>
    T* as2(T*) { /* ... */ }  
};
```

The former method is to be used like this:

```
    SomeComplexTypeAndNotAuto * a = foo.as1<SomeComplexTypeAndNotAuto>();
```

While the latter is more convenient to use since you don't need to repeat the complex type:

```
    SomeComplexTypeAndNotAuto * a = foo.as2(a);
```

However, most compiler rejects the 2nd case with a Wuninitialized warning:

```
warning: variable 'a' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]
```

It's quite clear the variable is not used in the initialization, only its type is. Is there a way to avoid this warning without dealing with the hell of per-compiler pragma ?

**Edit:**

It's not clear from my initial post, but when I wrote `SomeComplexTypeNotAuto`, I meant that such code like this:
`auto a = foo.as2(a);` can not be resolved since you **have** to provide one type to allow the compiler to deduce it.

My question was specific to the fact that method `as2()` is a template, as as such must be visible at specialization time for a type `T`. So the compiler can see that the argument `T*` does not even have a name so it's not used/usable from within the function. As such, I don't get why it warns about the "unused variable" warning since it's clear it's not used.

Comment: What do you mean by "complex type" exactly?

Comment: @idclev463035818 `where is a coming from? ` a is being declared.

Comment: @eerorika oh, missed that, now I am curious if `SomeComplexTypeAndNotAuto * a = foo.as1<decltype(a)>();` is allowed...

Comment: @idclev463035818 It's allowed.

Comment: @eerorika [yes it is ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830867/is-it-allowed-to-use-decltype-in-an-initializer-for-the-variable-that-is-decltyp)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, that's possible, but I'm sure you'd agree with me it's clearly not convenient to write ;-)

Comment: Re: "compiler rejects the 2nd case" -- the code is valid, and a conforming compiler is not allowed to reject it. Busybody compilers will **warn** about this, because it might be a coding error. If the compiler rejects it it's because there is some non-standard behavior, typically caused by setting a flag that tells the compiler to treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: @xryl669 actually no, i do not agree. Having a parameter only to deduce the template parameter is not convenient. The compiler is right at warning you about it. Even if you fix the UB and if you silence the warning, it will still be a surprise for anybody reading your code. On the other hand, `decltype` is made for exactly that purpose: deduce the type of a variable. I do agree that it isn't the nicest thing to write and actually you would need to remove the pointer from `a` to make it work, but if I had to choose between yours and `decltype` i would go for `decltype`

Comment: dont make the mistake of trying to minimize your keystrokes when writing code. Code should be explicit. Imho also `auto` is not primarily to save you from typing but to enable more generic code, breaking less code when refactoring, etc

Comment: @idclev463035818 We are shifting in the opinion domain here. IMHO, code from @AsteroidWithWings is cleaner, non repetitive, yours is painful to read and write (and also to maintain since if you rename a, you might forget to rename it in the decltype later on). As an evidence to what I'm saying, your example code is wrong since it's missing a `*` in the `decltype`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It's quite clear the variable is not used in the initialization

On the contrary, it is quite clear that the variable *is* used in the initialisation of the function argument. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Is this an incorrect warning?

No, the warning is correct.

---

A simple fix is to change the argument into a reference:

```
T* as2(T*&)
```

Just be extra sure to not actually read the referred value.

Since C+11, you can use `auto` instead however.

Comment: Not sure I see the benefit of passing by reference. If anything is assigned to `a` inside `as2`, it will be immediately overwritten by the assigment of what is returned from `as2`.

Comment: @JasperKent The argument is only used for deducing the template argument. The benefit of using a reference instead of a value is to allow what OP is trying to do.

Comment: Perfect example of what I said in my answer: this approach confuses readers of the code.

Comment: It could be a const reference instead so it's less confusing (at least, the variable can not be modified). But you are right that it confuses readers of the using code.

Comment: @xryl669 A const reference would likely raise warnings because passing an uninitialised object would appear pointless.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The objective is to deduce the type of `T`. Since if you write `T * b = f.as(b)`  and since `b` can be converted to a `T* const &`, `T` is deductible and as such can be assigned to `b` later on (please see the godbolt from previous comment for example code).

Comment: @xryl669 yeah, ignore my last (now deleted) comment :)

Answer (score 2):

The warning is correct.

`a` has an unspecified value in its own initialiser, and passing it as a function argument by value requires it to be copied, which requires reading from it, which has undefined behaviour.

It does not matter that you do not then use what would have been the resulting value.

---

You can "fix" it by preventing the copy (with a by-reference argument) but you're going to end up with very strange and unusual code that confuses your readers. I really do not advise this approach.

Just spell out the type, ideally making it shorter and more readable first.

Conventionally, we skip the repeated type name like this:

```
auto* a = foo.as1<SomeComplexTypeAndNotAuto>();
```

(e.g. when using `std::make_shared` and friends)

Also, look up the visitor pattern.

Comment: This is exactly for a visitor pattern. The `as()` method is used to "downcast" the visitor to the target type.

Comment: Please see the edit as I'm not convinced about the "requires reading from it" part.

Comment: Please notice that your answer with `auto * a` is probably the best solution if I had to write the code now. But the code I have is from a library and it's using the 2nd form. I've up'd your answer as it's definitively the way to do post C++11.

Comment: @xryl669 So the code is not yours, but is in a library you can't alter? That changes the question somewhat - the answer becomes "raise an issue with the library author, because it has a bug"! In the meantime, you can probably fork/patch it to fix the issue. Nowadays, there should be no problem using C++11 tools when you do that.

Comment: I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear that the variable is not used int the initialization. Anything could be happening inside `as2`.

If the variable is not being used, then don't pass it - use explicit template instantiation instead.

Comment: Sure, but you didn't read the example code carefully. From the method signature, it's clear it's not used, and the "explicit template instantiation" is painful to write.

Comment: It's certainly not clear from the signature. It may or may not be clear from the body, since although the template body must be visible to the compiler, it's still free to call functions which are not. Thus the compiler doesn't even bother to look.

Comment: Not sure what you "include" in a signature. The signature is `T* as2(T*)` and not `T* as2(T* b)` so without a variable name, how could the passed argument be read ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, signature includes function name and parameter types, not parameter names (nor return type) but I take your point. 

Still not enough to help the compiler, since it is possible to put a template definition separately from its specification, so a missing parameter name in the specification would not be enough in general to show it wasn't used. 

I suppose it would be conceivably possible to make a compiler that works like this in these specific circumstances, but as the warning suggests, it doesn't.

Comment: @xryl669: As I explained in my answer, even though the body cannot use the argument because it has been given no name, _merely calling the function uses the argument_ due to the copy. So, still, "it is clear that the variable is not used in the initialisation" is the opposite of true :)