# Is it allowed to use decltype in an initializer for the variable that is decltyped?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, decltype

Triggered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830000/is-this-an-incorrect-warning), I was wondering if, this is allowed:

```
template <typename T>
T foo(){return T{};}

struct bar {};

int main()
{

    bar a = foo<decltype(a)>();
}
```

Compilers I tried took it without complaints, but I am not sure if this is really legal or if I am missing any pitfalls (and it looks weird to use the type of `a` during its declaration).

For background: in the linked question OP wants to avoid `auto` and spelling out the type (here it is `bar`, `SomeComplexTypeAndNotAuto` in that question) twice at the same time, hence they use a (unused) parameter to deduce `T`. I didn't like misusing a parameter merely to deduce the type so my first idea was `decltype`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's kosher alright.

> **[basic.scope.pdecl]**
>
> [1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#pdecl-1) The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its
>   complete declarator ([dcl.decl]) and before its initializer (if any),
>   except as noted below. [ Example:
>
> ```
> unsigned char x = 12;
> { unsigned char x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here, the initialization of the second x has undefined behavior,
>   because the initializer accesses the second x outside its lifetime
>   ([basic.life]). — end example ]

So you can use `a` in its own initializer, since its declared at the point. The only question is how. `decltype` can be applied to an id-expression naming any variable in scope. And since the expression of `decltype` [is an unevaluated operand](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#decltype-1.sentence-2), there is no UB. Only the type of the variable is examined, not its indeterminate value.

No accounting for taste though.